# emulator - internet connection issue

Tags: android, emulation

I have set my proxy settings in emulator and I can access normal internet on emulator's browser. But when I try to run my application, it gives error
But when I change my URL to services running inside my organisation I can fetch data!!!

What is the issue here and how could I connect to URLs outside my org through my app???

Thanks
Abhinav Tyagi

ERROR:

> 05-11 17:12:28.867:
>   WARN/System.err(847):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://google.co.in 05-11
>   17:12:28.917: WARN/System.err(847):
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
>   05-11 17:12:28.917:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   com.xml.xml_test.getXML(xml_test.java:65)
>   05-11 17:12:28.928:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 05-11 17:12:28.939:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   05-11 17:12:28.957:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
>   05-11 17:12:28.957:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   05-11 17:12:28.968:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>   05-11 17:12:28.968:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   05-11 17:12:28.989:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-11 17:12:28.989:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   05-11 17:12:29.007:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   05-11 17:12:29.007:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 05-11 17:12:29.007:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   05-11 17:12:29.007:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-11 17:12:29.007:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   05-11 17:12:29.037:
>   WARN/System.err(847):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

here is my code:

```
         StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
         System.out.println("try");
         String registrationUrl = "http://google.com";
         url = new URL(registrationUrl);  
         System.out.println("url");
         URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 
         System.out.println("open connection");
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;         
         int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();  
         System.out.println(responseCode);
         is = conn.getInputStream();
         long len = 0;
         int ch = 0;
         len = conn.getContentLength();
         if (len != -1) {
             // Read exactly Content-Length bytes
             System.out.println("IF...");
             for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                 System.out.println("For Loop...");
                 if ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                     System.out.println("Appending");
                     b.append((char) ch);
                 }
             }
         } else {
             // Read till the connection is closed.
             System.out.println("Else...");
             while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                 System.out.println("When...");
                 len = is.available();
                 System.out.println("append");
                 b.append((char) ch);
             }
         }


         String data = b.toString();
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(data).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                xml_test.this.getParent();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please post your codes? Thanks

Comment: I have added my code, but its working fine with urls inside proxy !!!
Response code is coming as 403

Comment: do you mean you wanna apply proxy on ur app so that it can access internet thru your application via the proxy just like the web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have much time to go through what you actually need but if you wanna apply proxy to your application check the following examples..

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=13186

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/URLconnectionandproxy.htm

they're pretty much the same. sorry.. and good luck :)